# How to replace Hour/Minutes/Seconds in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a column with datetime values that look like this:

[image]

I would like to replace all the hours/minutes and seconds to be all 0s. something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try use [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) function:

```
SELECT date_trunc('DAY', '2021-01-27 14:00:28'::datetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using casting:

```
SELECT col_name::DATE
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT cast(CAST('2021-01-27 14:00:28' AS date) as datetime);
```

Be aware that the `[DATE_TRUNC][1]` function is not available in some versions of SQL.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html):

```
select regexp_replace('2021-12-02 01:03:50', ' [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}',' 00:00:00') as date;
```

I get:

```
2021-12-02 00:00:00
```

Using it on a table:

```
create or replace table t_time(t varchar(100));
insert into t_time values ('2021-12-02 01:35:20');
select t from t_time;
select regexp_replace(t, ' [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}',' 00:00:00'), t from t_time;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this because timestamps are usually stored in columns with TIMESTAMP data type, not VARCHAR data type. Date or datetime data manipulation is better done using date and datetime functions, not regexp functions which are better suited for character data manipulation.